# Centralizers of Cartan subgroups II

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field and let $\mathcal O$ be its ring of integers. Suppose that $2$ is split in $\mathcal O$. Let $k$ be a positive integer. The multiplicative group $(\mathcal O/2^k\mathcal O)^\times$ acts on the additive group $\mathcal O/2^k\mathcal O$ by multiplication. Therefore there is an embedding $(\mathcal O/2^k\mathcal O)^\times \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/ 2^k\mathbb Z)$. Let $C_k$ be the image. Is the centralizer of $C_k$ equal to $C_k$?

This follows my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327168/centralizers-of-cartan-subgroups).

A similar assertion for odd primes is stated without proof in this [paper, section 2](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~zywina/papers/Serre-Bound.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean to switch to $\mathbb Z/2^k/\mathbb Z$ after discussing $\mathcal O/2^k\mathcal O$?

Comment: @LSpice, What i meant was that $\mathcal O/ 2^k\mathcal O$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2^k\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2^k\mathbb Z $ and that this gives us the embedding.

Comment: Same answer as in the question this follows: the centraliser is contained in the normaliser, which is generated by $C$ and $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix})$. the latter acting non-trivially on $C$ so $C$ is its own centraliser. Or is there something different for $p=2$?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich, I do not understand why should the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ generate the normaliser. Can you please explain that or direct me to some reference?

Comment: You are in the split case, so you can choose the basis of $\mathcal{O}$ so that $C$ are just the diagonal matrices. Obviously that matrix is normalising and it is easy to check that the normaliser is $C\cup(\begin{smallmatrix}0&*\\*&0\end{smallmatrix})$.